# How to show nested array of json in html in ember.js

Tags: jquery, html, ajax, json, ember.js

I'm trying to show in html the json I receive in app.js but it's not working. Any ideas?

The code for the app.js (I'm sure that the $.post is returning a valid json)

```
App.CadeirasRoute = App.AuthenticatedRoute.extend({
  model: function() {
    alert(this.getUsername());
     $.post('/api/database/cadeira/', {"token": this.postJSONWithToken()}).then(function(response) {
        if (response.success) {
            alert(response.results[0].codigo); // this alerts right on browser with the right value of codigo of the first json in the array

            return response.results;
        }
     });
  }
});
```

my code in html

```
<script type="text/x-handlebars" id="cadeiras">
    <div id="cadeiras">
        {{#each item in model}}
      <h2>{{item.codigo}}</h2>
    {{/each}}
    </div>
  </script>
```

Comment: can you post a the code for the JSON response?

Answer (score 0):

the 'model' property is supposed to return a promise

[relevant api entry](http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.Route.html#method_model)

you are currently returning nothing

this may be solved by simply adding 'return' to this line

```
 return $.post('/api/database/cadeira/', {"token": this.postJSONWithToken()}).then(function(response) {
```

though I think I better solution that is more likely to work is to return an Ember promise

```
App.CadeirasRoute = App.AuthenticatedRoute.extend({
  model: function() {
    alert(this.getUsername());
    //create promise to be returned as per Ember api requirements
    return new Ember.RSVP.Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
        //submit ajax request similar to your previous one
        Ember.$.ajax({ 
            url: '/api/database/cadeira/',
            dataType: 'json',
            type: 'POST',
            data: {"token": this.postJSONWithToken()}),
            contentType: 'application/json'
        }).then(function(response) { //this handles a successful response
            alert(response.results[0].codigo);
            resolve(response.results);
        }, function(xhr) { //this handles a failed response
            var response = JSON.parse(xhr.responseText);
            Ember.run(function() {
                reject(response.error);
            });
        });
     });
  }
});
```

the first function passed into '.then()' is what happens on success, and the second is what happens on failure. resolve(value) passes a success through the promise and, in this case, allows model to be set to that 'resolved' value.

another links that might be useful

[Ember.RSVP.Promise](http://emberjs.com/api/classes/RSVP.Promise.html)

(a good example of custom token authenticators w/ promises)

[Ember Simple Auth custom server example](https://github.com/simplabs/ember-simple-auth/blob/master/examples/6-custom-server.html)